# Typescript to JSDoc

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, jsdoc

I'm wondering if it's possible for typescript types to be converted to jsdoc comments when it is compile

```js
// index.ts

function foo(a: string, b: number) : boolean {...}
```

then when you run `tsc index.js` the output file looks like this

```js
/**
* @param {string} a
* @param {number} b
* @returns {boolean}
*/
function foo(a, b) {...}
```

Is there a library that does this?